# Ajax.BeginForm triggers OnFailure with no reason

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5.2, ajax.beginform

I got stucked with (it seems to be) a simple problem.

My goal is to create a modal with an Ajax form. A child action gets the modal in a partial view, and when edited, submit button posts Ajax form which returns just Json data. Built-in code in Ajax.BeginForm should trigger OnSuccess or OnFailure depending on the result of the action.

The problem is OnFailure is triggered and OnSuccess don't, although the action finishes OK, and post return a 200 code. The "data" param in OnFailure function contains the HTML of the whole page.

This is the code:

(1) Snippet to load the modal in the main view:

```
<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
     @Html.Action("GetDialogV2", "Fianzas", new { idArrendamiento = Model.Id_Arrendamiento })
</div>
```

(2) Button to open the modal in the main view:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal">
      <i class="far fa-hand-holding-usd"></i>&nbsp;Modal
</button>
```

(3) The partial view with the modal (and the Ajax Form), GetDialogV2.cshtml:

```
@model EditFianzas_vm

@{
    AjaxOptions ajaxOptions = new AjaxOptions
    {
        HttpMethod = "POST",
        UpdateTargetId = "Respuesta",
        OnSuccess = "OnSuccess",
        OnFailure = "OnFailure"
    };
}

@using (Ajax.BeginForm(ajaxOptions))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h4 class="modal-title">Fianza</h4>
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                </button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <div class="form-horizontal">
                    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
                    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Id_Arrendamiento)

                    <div class="form-group">
                        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Importe, new { @class = "control-label col-md-6" })
                        <div class="col-md-8">
                            <div class="input-group">
                                <div class="input-group-prepend">
                                    <span class="input-group-text"><i class="far fa-euro-sign"></i></span>
                                </div>
                                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Importe, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control importe" } })
                            </div>
                            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Importe, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Fecha_Abono, new { @class = "control-label col-md-6" })
                        <div class="col-md-8">
                            <div class="input-group">
                                <div class="input-group-prepend">
                                    <span class="input-group-text"><i class="far fa-calendar"></i></span>
                                </div>
                                @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Fecha_Abono, "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}", new { @class = "form-control datepicker" })
                            </div>
                            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Fecha_Abono, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="col-md-8">
                            <input type="text" id="Respuesta" class="form-control" />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer justify-content-between">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Cancelar</button>
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="botonPrueba">Guardar</button>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- /.modal-content -->
    </div>
}
```

(4) The Javascript in the main view:

```
@section scripts
{
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function OnSuccess(data) {
            if (data.Success == true) {
                toastr.success("Operación realizada.", "Fianzas");
                $("#exampleModal").modal('hide');
            }
            else {
                if (data.modelState) {
                    $.each(d.modelState, function (i, item) {
                        toastr.info(i + ': ' + item, "i: item");
                        //item.valid(); //run jQuery validation to display error
                        $('#' + i).valid();
                    });
                }
                else {
                    toastr.error(data.Error, "Fianzas");
                }
            }
        }

        function OnFailure(data) {
            alert(data);
            alert('HTTP Status Code: ' + data.param1 + '  Error Message: ' + data.param2);
            toastr.error("Se ha producido un error no controlado al realizar la operación.", "Fianzas");
            toastr.warning(data, "Fianzas");
        }
    </script>
}
```

(5) And finally, the controller:

```
#region Ajax Form (GetDialogV2)
public PartialViewResult GetDialogV2(int idArrendamiento)
{
    //Obtengo el modelo...
    Arrendamientos_Fianzas fianza = db.Arrendamientos_Fianzas.Find(idArrendamiento);
    //Creo la vista-modelo...
    EditFianzas_vm vm = new EditFianzas_vm {
        Id_Arrendamiento = idArrendamiento,
        Importe = fianza.Importe,
        Fecha_Abono = fianza.Fecha_Abono
    };

    return PartialView(vm);
}

[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public JsonResult GetDialogV2(EditFianzas_vm vm)
{
    try
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var modelState = ModelState.ToDictionary
            (
                kvp => kvp.Key,
                kvp => kvp.Value.Errors.Select(e => e.ErrorMessage).ToArray()
            );
            modelState.Add("hdId_Arrendamiento", modelState["vm.Id_Arrendamiento"]);
            modelState.Remove("vm.Id_Arrendamiento");
            modelState.Add("txtImporte", modelState["vm.Importe"]);
            modelState.Remove("vm.Importe");
            modelState.Add("txtFecha_Abono", modelState["vm.Fecha_Abono"]);
            modelState.Remove("vm.Fecha_Abono");
            return Json(new { modelState }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
            //throw (new Exception("Error en la validación del modelo."));
        }
        //Miro a ver si existen datos para este arrendamiento (no sé si es un edit o un new, si quiero hacerlo todo en una misma acción)
        Arrendamientos_Fianzas fianza = db.Arrendamientos_Fianzas.Find(vm.Id_Arrendamiento);
        //Compruebo si es nuevo o editado...
        if (fianza == null)
        {
            //Nuevo registro...
            fianza = new Arrendamientos_Fianzas
            {
                Id_Arrendamiento = vm.Id_Arrendamiento,
                Importe = vm.Importe,
                Fecha_Abono = vm.Fecha_Abono
            };
            //Actualizo info de control...
            fianza.C_Fecha = DateTime.Now;
            fianza.C_IdUsuario = Usuario.NombreUsuario;
            fianza.C_Comentarios = "Alta de la fianza.";
            //Guardo registro...
            db.Arrendamientos_Fianzas.Add(fianza);
        }
        else
        {
            //Estoy editando, grabo valores...
            fianza.Importe = vm.Importe;
            fianza.Fecha_Abono = vm.Fecha_Abono;
            //Actualizo info de control...
            fianza.C_Fecha = DateTime.Now;
            fianza.C_IdUsuario = Usuario.NombreUsuario;
            fianza.C_Comentarios = "Modificación de los datos de la fianza.";
            //Modifico estado del registro en el modelo...
            db.Entry(fianza).State = EntityState.Modified;
        }
        //Guardo cambios...
        db.SaveChanges();
        //Return...
        return new JsonResult() { Data = Json(new { Success = true }) };
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return new JsonResult() { Data = Json(new { Success = false, Error = ex.Message }) };
    }
}
#endregion
```

Thanks a lot in advance for your time and help.

Best regards,
Fernando.

Answer (score 0):

I got it. It was a subtle solution, as I barely guessed:

If Javascript is disabled, or in certain circumstances, you need to explicitly pass action to the AjaxOptions, like that:

```
    AjaxOptions ajaxOptions = new AjaxOptions()
    {
        HttpMethod = "POST",
        OnSuccess = "OnSuccess(data)",
        OnFailure = "OnFailure",
        OnBegin = "OnBegin",
        OnComplete = "OnComplete",
        Url = Url.Action("GetDialogV2")
    };
```